# Parent State machine transition in Hierarchical State Machines

Tags: state, hierarchical

I am a novice at Hierarchical State Machines.

When a parent state transitions to another state, what happens to the child state?  Does it stay in the current state?

I am wanting to transition from a parent state called running to a parent state called fault.  Once the fault is cleared, I want to transition back to the running state and enter the first child state.

Steven

Answer (score 0):

1. running to fault: put an trigger referring Event named "EVT_Fault"
2. for example, "low" and "high" are two substates of running
3. put an initial node inside running and target to "low"
4. put a transition from falut to running, don't put any trigger to the transition. (This is completion transition)

Suppose low is the active state, trigger EVT_Fault, following sequence happened:

```
low.exit

running.exit

transition_running_to_fault.effect

fault.entry

(when entry finished, since there is completion transition)

fault.exit

transition_fault_to_running.effect

running.entry

transition_initial_to_low.entry
```

Answer (score 0):

When a parent state is exited, its child state should also exit.

To achieve the re-entry of child state when the parent state is re-entered, you need a history pseudo state (deep or shallow depending on the depth of your child state).

See an example here: http://www.steelbreeze.net/state.js/#examples - pressing the 'flip' button twice shows deep history in action.

DMM